# Nuget package referenced in 2 assemblies does not work

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget, .net-assembly

I have a solution that is built like that:

***ProjectA -> Assembly2 -> Assembly1 -> NuGet Package (Newtonsoft.JSON)***

I'm currently developing on Assembly2, which has a dependency to Assembly1. I debug with ProjectA. So long, the Newtonsoft.dll is copied to my bin folder, and everything works.

Now I want to use Newtonsoft directly in my Assembly2, so I added it as NuGet Package. After that, the Newtonsoft.dll is no longer copied to the bin folder.

I tried to download the Newtonsoft.dll directly (or use the Newtonsoft.dll from Assembly1 directly via 'Browse...'). This works, too.
It seems, that this problems only occur, when I use NuGet in Assembly2. Can someone explain this behaviour?

EDIT:
I used the exact same Version of Newtonsoft and
I'm using .Net Standard(2.0) for both my Assemblies and .NET Framework(4.7.2) for my Project (Console App).

Transitive Dependencies do not work here, I think. I do not reference another project (where I can see the Assy1.deps.json), but the built DLL.

Comment: MSBuild binlog, which you can view with https://msbuildlog.com, contain everything that MSBuild did, so you can figure it out that way. If you can share a [reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then someone else can probably do the analysis for you.

Comment: could you place a screenshot of your project explorer (assuming, you use VS) with the references expanded? I guess if you say project, you mean solution, and by assembly you mean project. But might be wrong :-)

Comment: on the first sight I would say, you are not using json in your assy2. you referencing Assy1 as a dll, it's fine, but there could be some optimization on build, where unneeded references will be ignored, therefore ignored on build assy2. Maybe there is an option on the reference-entry in the project browser, like "Local Copy=true" (I'm afraid, I mixed up your indexes :-))

Comment: Never add a dependecy to dll in other project's output folder. This is opaque and brittle. If you have other references in your project tree set up the same way then this may be the cause of the troubles you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! 
I tried reading the MSBuild Log, but cannot find anything obvious. I'm trying to create a reproducable example the next days.
I cannot screenshot my solution, because of our work rules. 
But I can tell. Assy1 and Assy2 are projects (Class Libraries, DLLs), ProjectA is a simple ConsoleApp project just for testing.

Comment: Q: what type of csproj is being used here? Is it the "old" (very verbose) style? or does it use the "new" (concise) csproj format? Another clue is if you have a packages.josn file in the projects.       The rules around references are different with the "new" more concise csproj format

Comment: I am using the new csproj, I think. I edited my question and added it.

Answer (score 2):

Puzzling for sure. From your description that ought to be fine, but...

"Transitive dependencies" are your friend.
If assy1 references NS.Json, and assy2 refs assy1, then NS.Json is available to assy2. There is no need to ref NS.Json from assy2.

This is a-good-thing. It means that some versioning hell is removed. If you want to upgrade NS.Json then you only have 1 place to do that. The ref is not scattered all over your projects.
This works well if you also follow the good practice of having a "clean" dependency graph.

Comment: OP: "Now I want to use Newtonsoft directly in my Assembly2". Hence, it is not just a transitive dependency anymore, but a direct one.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. So is it common sense to use the DLLs from assy1 in assy2 by directly referring to them (Add Reference, Browse... )?

Comment: @imre there's a diff between "using" and needing a direct reference. We may be talking about slightly different things? But assy2 does not need a direct ref in order to use the newtonsoft bits

Comment: @towa I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, but... I would recommend -not- adding a direct ref to NS in assy2. Just rely on the transitive ref from assy1. ... Everything that assy1 can see is available for use in assy2.

Comment: I am using .net standard 2.0 and not .net core. I cannot find any information about transitive dependencies with .net standard 2.0. Also I don't know how to access Newtonsoft from Assy2 through Assy1. I have to reference the Newtonsoft dll directly in Assy2 to get it working

Comment: hmmm... ok. "Transitive" is actually a function of the build system, not ns or core or framework.   Q: are you still using the "old" csproj format and packages.json?    if so, then please ignore the transitive suggestion

Comment: if you want to see where transitive started, see https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/199 (but not an easy read :D )

Comment: Hey, I did some research and found out transitive dependencies only work when referencing directly to another project, and NOT when referencing to a already built dll (as it is in my case). Would it help to set up a nuget package source and manage my dlls via nuget? i appreciate your help

Comment: that might be true if the "pre-built dll" is still using "old" style csproj. For "sdk" style csproj, transitive will/should work regardless of reference type. 
Sure, building your "libraries" to nuget makes sense. Especially if they are used in many places. But there is some extra work involved. Especially if those packages change frequently. (nothing is ever "free")
Using sdk style csproj (in the things that ref the packages) makes updating the package versions _much_ easier.